# How to prevent ${aspnet-request-posted-body} to not log sensitive info

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

I am using  `${aspnet-request-post-body}`  to log the request body in log file. The problem I am facing: I want to prevent `${aspnet-request-post-body}` to log some info i.e password and credit card details and I like to apply masking on them.

For example if request body is
`{username : ABC, password :554&3}`
this should be logged in this format
`{username: ABC, password : ****}`

Please note I have already tried replace layout for this problem and don't want to use this. Is there any other way to do this task?

Comment: Maybe create an advanced NLog LayoutRenderer that can parse a document (xml / json) and can specify transformations of property-values. Ex from `password: "xyz"` to `password: "***"`.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/4145

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `${aspnet-request-post-body}` is only text for NLog.

So you have the following options:

- replace all stuff (with a regex): example of config with replace all:

  ```xml
  <variable name="messageNoDigits" 
    value="${replace:inner=${message}:searchFor=(\\d{3\})+:replaceWith=:regex=true}" />
  ```
- write your own custom layout renderer that parses the body as JSON and transforms it. Please note that reading the body in ASP.NET Core could be a bit tricky, see [the current code in NLog for it](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/blob/master/src/Shared/LayoutRenderers/AspNetRequestPostedBody.cs). If you have the code for reading/transforming the body, it could be easily converted to a NLog layout renderer:

  ```cs
  using NLog.Web.LayoutRenderers; 

  // register ${SanitizedBody}
  AspNetLayoutRendererBase.Register("SanitizedBody", (logEventInfo, httpContext, loggingConfiguration) => MyMethod(httpContext));
  ```

  See https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-layout-renderer